# get_context_data function doesn't return the 'form'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following Django code (django version 1.11) of a form:

```
class MyDocumentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    """ We extend UpdateView as we need to pass self.object in context as resource """
    model = MyDocument

    def get_context_data(self, **context):

        context[self.context_object_name] = self.object
        context['resource'] = self.object
        #context['form'] = self.get_form() <-- if I uncomment this it works
        return context

class DocumentUpdateView(MyDocumentUpdateView):
    form_class = MyDocumentForm
    def form_valid(self, form):
        doc = form.save(commit=False)
        doc.owner = self.request.user
        updateMyDocument(doc, form)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse(
                'mydocs_detail',
                args=(
                    self.object.slug,
                )))
```

When I run this code, I get an error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

I realized that this error related with the return of the **context** variable. For some reason the context dictionary does not include the 'form'. As indicated [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_context_data):

```
get_context_data(**kwargs)¶
Calls get_form() and adds the result to the context data with the name ‘form’.
```

But in my case the context dictionary does not include the 'form'.

If I use the get_form() def, then everything works:

```
context['form'] = self.get_form()
```

But this seems like an overkill to me and I want to dig deeper on why this doesn't work.

Then I have noticed that in my case I use:

```
def get_context_data(self, **context):
```

instead of:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
```

So I defined the context as following:

```
context = super(DocumentUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

But then I get the following error:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: I don't think this piece of code is really relevent as we can't see no access to `fields` attribute here

Comment: Can you please post the *full* traceback for you `'str' object has no attribute 'fields'`? It looks like this is another error (something with your specific `Form`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I defined the context as following:
>
> ```
> context = super(DocumentUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
> ```

You used the wrong class, since you call this at the `MyDocumentUpdateView` level, it should be `super(MyDocumentUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`. So you should implement this as:

```
class MyDocumentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    """ We extend UpdateView as we need to pass self.object in context as resource """
    model = MyDocument

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyDocumentUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['resource'] = self.object
        return context
```

That being said, the `self.object` is already added to the context, by default as the name of the model (so here that would be `mydocument`, and you can specify one on your own by specifying a value for the `context_object_name` attribute, like:

```
class MyDocumentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    """ We extend UpdateView as we need to pass self.object in context as resource """
    model = MyDocument
    context_object_name = 'resource'
```

in that case, the context of course has no longer the object stored under its model name (or any other name).

Comment: I see. That worked! I wonder, which method is better. What you suggest or just to use the get_form(). Is there a difference?